# Put an image on another

Tags: html, css

I am stuck concerning the manipulation of two images. My goal is to arrive at the same result see below screenshot.

[image]

So, I have a banner and another image and I want the second image enters in the banner because for now I don't see my second image.
Is it a problem with my block html ?

```
<div class="my-second-block">
    <img class="picture-red" src="images/bg-1.jpg"/>
    <div class="contenu">
    <img class="picture-pc" src="images/welimg.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.picture-red{
  height: 400px; /*400*/
  width: 1366px; /*1366*/
  position: absolute;
}

.contenu{
  margin-top: 500px;
}

.picture-pc{
  float: left;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add positioning and z-index. For example:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

to the desired image that you want to be on the top.